# Difference between created queue and global queue. Swift 3

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I am still attempting to grasp the idea of dispatch queue

I understand that the difference between created queues and global queues is that the global executes concurrently while the created queue executes serially.

**SERIAL (created queue)**

`let anotherQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.anotherQueue", qos: .utility)`

**CONCURRENT (global queue)**

`let globalQueue = DispatchQueue.global()`

However, what if I specified that the created queue be concurrent like this:

---

**Concurrent Created Queue**

`let anotherQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.anotherQueue", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)`

Will the created queue be the same as global queue then?

Answer (score 0):

global concurrent queues may not be modified (suspend, resume, set_context, etc., will have no effect).